# Reference request: sums of rational functions and polygamma functions

Tags: reference-request, special-functions

I have heard that there are ways to express sums of rational functions in terms of polygamma functions, and I would like to read more about it. However, I don't know the literature about special functions very well. Can anybody suggest possible references? Thank you.

Comment: this is explained on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Evaluation_of_sums_of_rational_functions

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Yes, I  have read that page indeed. I was wondering if there are some more "formal" sources, maybe also with some extra background information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a journal publication with many generalisations is

[Infinite sums as linear combinations of polygamma functions](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Infinite-sums-as-linear-combinations-of-polygamma-Pilehrood-Pilehrood/6c3a7246b5cf2478c5714593c7ee8bd1802c8887), Kh. Hessami Pilehrood, T. Hessami Pilehrood, Acta Arithmetica **130** (2007) 231-254.

Comment: Thank you, this will do! Don't get me wrong, I am fond of wikipedia, I just wanted to go a bit more in deep into the subject.